# scrollToRowAtIndexPath always returns 0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

There appears to be lots of sample code to do this and I swear I have tried every one of them.  Nothing I try gets the row that was selected.

Now, I will tell you that I have a scroll view with a table view in it.  The table view is filled with labels and text boxes.  I am trying to move the selected row to just above keyboard when keyboard is displayed.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  Also, any sample code would be great!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No one can help you unless you post the code you are using.

Comment: #pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Store the selected indexPath
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

Comment: That didn't work out well, did it.  I'll try again:

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectedRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}

Comment: As I said before, the value is always 0.

Comment: If I hard code a cell index, my move code works.

Comment: OK.  I've changed my code around so much and I just tested it.  This method is no longer getting called.

Comment: You need to update your question with the code.

Comment: OK.  When I click on a label in the row, that delegate method gets called and returns the correct value.  It's when I click on the text box in the row (of course) the method is not called.  

So I need code to execute when the text box is entered (or keyboard is displayed) that discovers the row the text box is in.